# how to convert datetime to facebook format?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

i would like to know if there is a away that converts time from that format  {3/16/2014 7:07:25 AM} to facebook format like one hour ago etc i am working on windows phone 8 application

Comment: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow_

Comment: Let me answe the question still. Yes, there is a way. Answered.

Answer (score 1):

Beside seasrching for a library, it's not really hard to code one of such functions yourself. This is something I've used in the past:

```
public static string ConvertToFacebookLikeTime(DateTime value)
        {
            const int SECOND = 1;
            const int MINUTE = 60 * SECOND;
            const int HOUR = 60 * MINUTE;
            const int DAY = 24 * HOUR;
            const int MONTH = 30 * DAY;

            TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now - value;
            double delta = ts.TotalSeconds;

            if (delta < 0)
            {
                return "Right Now";
            }
            if (delta < 1 * MINUTE)
            {
                //return ts.Seconds == 1 ? "one second ago" : ts.Seconds + " seconds ago";
                return "A Few Seconds Ago";
            }
            if (delta < 2 * MINUTE)
            {
                return "A Minute Ago";
            }
            if (delta < 45 * MINUTE)
            {
                return ts.Minutes + "Minutes Ago";
            }
            if (delta < 90 * MINUTE)
            {
                return "An Hour Ago";
            }
            if (delta < 24 * HOUR)
            {
                return ts.Hours + " Hours Ago";
            }
            if (delta < 48 * HOUR)
            {
                return "Yesterday";
            }
            if (delta < 30 * DAY)
            {
                return ts.Days + " Days Ago";
            }
            if (delta < 12 * MONTH)
            {
                int months = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor((double)ts.Days / 30));
                return months <= 1 ? "A Month Ago" : months + "Months Ago";
            }
            else
            {
                int years = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor((double)ts.Days / 365));
                return years <= 1 ? "A Year Ago" : years + " Years Ago";
            }
        }
```